# VS Code wrong ruler lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, rulers

I am trying to add rulers to my editor. However, the rulers are way off. I tried offsetting them but the offset changes from file to file.

[image: The columns are drawn at 93 and 102]

I am adding the settings json file as well where the rulers are set at 72 and 79.

```
    {
    "window.closeWhenEmpty": false,
    "editor.emptySelectionClipboard": false,
    "editor.dragAndDrop": false,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro",
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.selectionHighlight": true,
    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "editor.scrollBeyondLastLine": true,
    "window.title": "${activeEditorShort}${separator}${rootName}",
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai Darker",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp.default.cStandard": "c11",
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\Box Sync",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace",
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
    "editor.letterSpacing": 2,
    "terminal.integrated.letterSpacing": 2,
    "markdown.preview.lineHeight": 2,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "editor.rulers": [
        72,79
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The font I was using did not have a uniform width. Hence, although I was setting up rulers, they were not accurate. I currently use Fira Code and the rulers now work fine.